# How many solutions are there to $x^3\equiv-1\pmod{365}$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, number-theory, elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, chinese-remainder-theorem

> How many solutions are there to $x^3\equiv-1\pmod{365}$?

I found that there is only one solution mod $5$, but mod $73$ I'm a little confused. Factoring out $x^3 + 1=(x+1)(x^2-x+1)$, the second equation has no real solutions, hence $x\equiv-1\pmod{73}$ is the only solution mod $73$. So by the Chinese remainder theorem, there is only $1*1=1$ solution. Is this correct?

Comment: What was $9^3$?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Note that $x^3+1$ factors as $x^3+1=(x+1)(x^2-x+1)$, where $x^2-x+1$ is irreducible in $\Bbb{F}_5[x]$. So indeed there is only one solution $\mod5$. But in $\Bbb{F}_{73}[x]$ we have
$$x^3+1=(x+1)(x+8)(x-9),$$
so there are *three* solutions $\mod{73}$, which are $-1$, $-8$ and $9$. By the Chinese remainder theorem we then have $1\times3=3$ solutions.

Answer (score 4):

See @Servaes for a very nice answer.

For something a bit more systematic, $73$ is prime and so there is a primitive root $g$ modulo $73$.  Every element of $\Bbb Z_{73}$ except for $0$ (which is not a solution) can be written as $x=g^k$ for some $k=0,1,2,\ldots,71$.  Since $-1\equiv g^{36}$ we have
$$\eqalign{x^3\equiv-1\pmod{73}\quad
  &\Leftrightarrow\quad g^{3k}\equiv g^{36}\pmod{73}\cr
  &\Leftrightarrow\quad 3k\equiv36\pmod{72}\ ;\cr}$$
since $\gcd(3,72)=3$ and this is a factor of $36$, there are three solutions.

Comment: How do you know that there is a $g$ such that $g^{36}\equiv-1\pmod{73}$?

Comment: any idea why that is the case? Is it from a theorem?

Comment: Yes, look up something like "primitive roots modulo prime".  If you have not yet studied this topic you would be better to go with @Servaes' answer.

Comment: I did learn this same topic hence I'm even more confused as to how that conclusion was derived. Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: $g^{72}\equiv1$, definition of primitive root.  Taking square roots (ok modulo a prime), $g^{36}\equiv\pm1$.  But $g^{36}\equiv1$ would contradict the definition of a primitive root.